# http: content negotiation, object oriented

Tags: http

I am reading about HTTP, and I have questions about its 'content negotiation' and 'object-oriented' features.

It is said that when an HTTP Server is able to send multiple representation of a single resource, content negotiation is used to decide which representation to send. What would be an example of this in practice? I cannot figure out what would be a situation of multiple representation of a single resource, because I am simply typing in a URL starting with http and that URL is uniquely identifying one resource?

I also read somewhere it says http is "object oriented", what does it mean?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what could possibly be meant by "Object Oriented" related to HTTP. That's a term for programming languages.

When you type in a URL, that's not the only thing sent to a Web server. The browser also adds a number of *headers*. These may be calculated from the computer's locale (localized language and format settings) and other constraints. Content negotiation headers take the form (where q=quality level):

```
`Accept-<aspect>: option1; q=<value1>, option2; q=<value2>`
```

Such as:

```
Accept-Language: de; q=1.0, en; q=0.5
```

Meaning: I prefer your German page, but English is an OK second choice.

This way, users from all over the world can go to Google.com and get a search page in their native language.

(Borrowed from: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_negotiation)

Comment: Thanks, that's a great example

Answer (score 0):

Projects I've worked on have allowed several different kinds of responses, based on what is requested.  For instance, given the URL (fictional and illustrative) `http://example.com/catalog/item/23956`, I may want that same route to map to a JSON representation of my item, to an HTML page that gives details of the item, or even to a pdf, depending on what is requested.

The request contains an `Accept` header that, for example, may look like `text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8`, specifying that it wants html, xhtml, or xml.

Other headers include `Accept-Language`, specifying which languages are preferred, and `Accept-Encoding`, which among other things can be used to let a server know that the client is able to decompress data sent to it (e.g. gzip'd)

A well-designed web server could change its response based on what content type is requested, and not just require some sort of identifier in the route (e.g. ending in `.htm` or `.pdf`)